# How to move list-items to a new column if they extend past the height of the container?

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a list where I'd like to build two columns from.
The list can have a variable amount of items in it, but a max. of 8

I always want the first column to have 4 elements. 
I already tried `column-count: 2` but this does not work fine on an uneven number, because the first row must contain 4 elements.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox):

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
li {
  height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```